# How to package xml with service definition into ear for jboss?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ear

Currently I have an ear and a `my-service.xml` with mbean definition. It runs on jboss 4.2.3 GA.

Currently I have to deploy the xml first and then ear. I'd like to bundle them together. How should I put xml inside ear? what's the required directory structure? should i add some meta information in some ear descriptors? do i have to wrap it into sar archive or i can just add the xml to the ear?

Comment: since MDBs and EJBs exist at the same tier, i'd recommend bundling it into an ejb-jar (either an existing on in the project, or a new one).  then you can bundle the ejb-jar into the ear file and it should all deploy nicely.